# How does SAS input an integer by format like x.y

Tags: sas

My friend asked me a question:

```
data _null_;
  test = input(12,4.2);
  put test = ;
run;
```

The result is 0.12, why?

I do some test on this and I guess **SAS read the string '12' from right to left to determin the position of decimal point**. When I test `test = input(123,4.2);`, it gives me `1.23` which support my assumption. But when I test `test = input(12.0,4.2);`, it returns `12`. So I do more test on this and have another guess: **SAS have different policy on inputing decimal and integer**.

Am I right? Or you have other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=n14sqpf1cubqknn1vmkzkp1oph87.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).  Your kerfuffle is explained by "If the data contains decimal points,"

> **w.d Informat**
> Reads standard numeric data.
> ...
> **Syntax**
> *w.d*
> **Syntax Description**
> ***w***
> specifies the width of the input field.
> Range   1–32
> ***d***
> specifies the power of 10 by which to divide the value. **If the data contains decimal points, the *d* value is ignored**. This argument is optional.
> Range   0–31